# Execute bash script within package.json

Tags: npm

I am trying to run an NPM script that relies on a variable that needs to be assigned at runtime.

**package.json**

```
{
  "version": "4.0.10",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "set-version": "VERSION=(sentry-cli releases propose-version)",
    "release": "sentry-cli releases new -p internal-app $VERSION --finalize",
    ...
  }
}
```

I've attempted to set the variable in the `set-version` script however once I run `release`, the variable is not known.

How can I set this up so that when I run `npm run release` the variable `$VERSION` is known?

Comment: have you tried an environment variable? or script writing out your package.json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the environment variable and run the command all at once:

```
    "release": "VERSION=(sentry-cli releases propose-version) sentry-cli releases new -p internal-app $VERSION --finalize",
```

If only your command line is using `$VERSION` you can inline it:

```
    "release": "sentry-cli releases new -p internal-app `sentry-cli releases propose-version` --finalize",
```

Comment: Perfect.  the inline solution is what I was looking for.